# Unable to login to MongoDB using a user created in the init.js file

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a local MongoDB database that I'm spinning up using Docker. In my docker-compose file, I'm creating an admin user as well as running an init script:

```
services:
  mongodb:
    hostname: mymongo
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: muser
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mpassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydatabase

    volumes:
      - ../mongodb/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro   

    ports:
      - 27018:27017
```

In that `mongo-init.js` file, I'm creating the database, collections, and a user:

```
db = new Mongo().getDB("mydatabase");
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "newuser",
        pwd: "newpass",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "mydatabase"
            }
        ]
    }
);
 
db.createCollection('users', { capped: false });
db.createCollection('data', { capped: false });

db.users.createIndex({ user_id: 1 })
```

The database, collections, indexes, and user all get created, however, I'm unable to connect to the MongoDB via Compass using the newuser/newpass  combo. I am successfully able to connect using the muser/mpassword created in the docker compose file above. Inside Compass, `db.getUsers()` reports that the user was created:

```
{
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'mydatabase.hfuser',
      userId: new UUID("e5024621-5dc1-4372-86c4-789a84fb85e1"),
      user: 'hfuser',
      db: 'mydatabase',
      roles: [Array],
      mechanisms: [Array]
    }
  ],
  ok: 1
}
```

`db.auth('hfuser', 'hfpass')` also reports that things are fine:

```
{ ok: 1 }
```

I've also tested this using the PyMongo library and I also encounter the same issues with the respective users:

```
MONGODB = pymongo.MongoClient(host='localhost', username='hfuser', port=27018, password='hfpass').mydatabase
MONGODB.data.insert_one({'data': 'stuff'})

pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

Is there a flag, role, or setting that I'm missing?

Comment: try setting the `authSource` parameter to either `admin` or your database name.